# prime factorization using sieve method

Tags: c++, c, primes, prime-factoring

What's wrong with my code ?

I am trying  to find the prime factor, but it didn't work after getting input it crash's.

What should I do now ? I am using separate method to generate the primes after generating prime i just call the prime function in main.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<math.h>
#define SIZE 1000000
using namespace std;
long p[SIZE],input;
long List[SIZE];  // saves the List
long listSize;   // saves the size of List

void prime(void)
{
       long i,j;
       p[0]=1;
       p[1]=1;
       for(i=2;i<=sqrt(SIZE);i++)  // prime generate part
            if(p[i]==0)
                for(j=2;j*i<=SIZE;j++)
                    p[i*j]=1;
}

void primeFactorize( long n )
{
    listSize = 0;   // Initially the List is empty, we denote that size = 0
    long sqrtN = long( sqrt(n) ); // find the sqrt of the number
    for( long i = 0; p[i] <= sqrtN; i++ ) { // we check up to the sqrt
        if( n % p[i] == 0 ) { // n is multiple of prime[i]
            // So, we continue dividing n by prime[i] as long as possible
            while( n % p[i] == 0 ) {
                n /= p[i]; // we have divided n by prime[i]
                List[listSize] = p[i]; // added the ith prime in the list
                listSize++; // added a prime, so, size should be increased
            }
            // we can add some optimization by updating sqrtN here, since n
            // is decreased. think why it's important and how it can be added
        }
    }
    if( n > 1 )
    {
        // n is greater than 1, so we are sure that this n is a prime
        List[listSize] = n; // added n (the prime) in the list
        listSize++; // increased the size of the list
    }
}
int main()
{
    prime();    
    while(scanf_s("%ld",&input),input)
    {
          if(input==1)
                printf("1 = 1\n");
            else if(input==-1)
                printf("-1 = -1 x 1\n");
            else
            {
                primeFactorize( input );

            }
    for( long i = 0; i < listSize; i++ ) // traverse the List array
                printf("%d ", List[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "What should I do now ?" - open up the debugger...

Comment: Your code may crash in the `prime()` function because you loop until `j*i<=SIZE` and then access `p[i*j]` which is out of bounds when `j*i==SIZE`. You should use `j*i<SIZE` as the condition in your `for` loop. It's probably not your only error... As @MitchWheat suggested: use a debugger to find the line where you crash.

Comment: If you start by giving an input of `1`, you never set `listSize` and yet you try to go through a loop to print out values. You have to initialize outside of the `primeFactorize` function.

Answer (score 1):

In your `prime()` routine, you set flags to indicate whether a number is prime or not - the ones with a `1` in them are not prime. However, in the `primeFactorize` function you are assuming that the array `p[]` contains the values of the primes, not a flag. So you very soon get to a divide-by-zero (since the flag of a prime number is zero), and you crash.

You need to make sure that the array that you access has the numbers you expect in it!

A possible approach would be to create two arrays: `pflags` and `pvalues`. When you first go through setting flags in your `prime()` function, you should be setting `pflags`. After you have looped over all possible values, you scrape the array `pflags` for zero values; every time you encounter one, you set the next value of `pvalues` to the index of `pflags`. Something like this:

```
void prime(void)
{
  long i,j;
  pflags[0]=1;
  pflags[1]=1;
  for(i=2;i<=sqrt(SIZE);i++)  // prime generate part
    if(pflags[i]==0)
      for(j=2;j*i<SIZE;j++)
        pflags[i*j]=1;
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    if(flags[i]==0) pvalues[j++]=i;
  }     
}
```

Of course you must initialize these arrays properly, and use `pvalues` instead of `p` in the `primeFactorize` function. If you are clever, you will see that you could in fact use the same array `p` for both these things - but it's tricky to keep straight in your head what you are doing, so using two separate arrays will help in understanding.

**EDIT** I decided to see if I could get the code to run - and it does (after fixing one typo, changing the `scanf_s` function to `scanf`, and fixing the formatting of the output from `%d` to `%ld`). I also cleaned up the I/O a little bit. To help you I include the complete listing that works for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<math.h>
#define SIZE 1000000
using namespace std;
long pvalues[SIZE], pflags[SIZE], input;
long List[SIZE];  // saves the List
long listSize;   // saves the size of List


void prime(void)
{
  long i,j;
  pflags[0]=1;
  pflags[1]=1;
  for(i=2;i<=sqrt(SIZE);i++)  // prime generate part
    if(pflags[i]==0)
      for(j=2;j*i<SIZE;j++)
        pflags[i*j]=1;
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    if(pflags[i]==0) pvalues[j++]=i;
  }     
}
void primeFactorize( long n )
{
    listSize = 0;   // Initially the List is empty, we denote that size = 0
    long sqrtN = long( sqrt(n) ); // find the sqrt of the number
    for( long i = 0; pvalues[i] <= sqrtN; i++ ) { // we check up to the sqrt
        if( n % pvalues[i] == 0 ) { // n is multiple of prime[i]
            // So, we continue dividing n by prime[i] as long as possible
            while( n % pvalues[i] == 0 ) {
                n /= pvalues[i]; // we have divided n by prime[i]
                List[listSize] = pvalues[i]; // added the ith prime in the list
                listSize++; // added a prime, so, size should be increased
            }
            // we can add some optimization by updating sqrtN here, since n
            // is decreased. think why it's important and how it can be added
        }
    }
    if( n > 1 )
    {
        // n is greater than 1, so we are sure that this n is a prime
        List[listSize] = n; // added n (the prime) in the list
        listSize++; // increased the size of the list
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    prime();    
    printf("\nEnter number to factorize: ");
    while(scanf("%ld",&input),input)
    {
          if(input==1)
                printf("1 = 1\n");
            else if(input==-1)
                printf("-1 = -1 x 1\n");
            else
            {
                primeFactorize( input );

            }
    printf("The number %ld has the following factors: ", input);
    for( long i = 0; i < listSize; i++ ) // traverse the List array
                printf("%ld ", List[i]);
    printf("\n\nEnter number to factorize: ");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tested this for a few different inputs:

```
Enter number to factorize: 81
The number 81 has the following factors: 3 3 3 3 

Enter number to factorize: 123
The number 123 has the following factors: 3 41 

Enter number to factorize: 64
The number 64 has the following factors: 2 2 2 2 2 2 

Enter number to factorize: 0

(exits)
```

All exactly as expected.

Comment: dude @Will Ness I used it but it didn't give me the output like for 4 , output will be 2 2 . but it gives 4 .                                                      void primeFactorize( long n ){
    listSize = 0;
    long sqrtN = (long)sqrt((double)n);//
    for( long i = 2; i <= sqrtN; i++ ) { //i = 0 ---> i = 2 and p[i] ---> i (Same below)
  while( n % pvalues[i] == 0 ) {//possible [if statement] is omitted
   n /= pvalues[i];//!
   List[listSize] = pvalues[i];//!
            listSize++;
        }
    }
    if( n > 1 )
    {
        List[listSize] = n;
        listSize++;
    }
}

Comment: what should I do now ?

Comment: @Floris is the one who answered you; I merely tweaked the formatting of their answer. :) [your code, formatted](http://ideone.com/WeP6Dx): use `i` instead of `pvalues[i]`; `List` must be defined somewhere in the global scope as `long List[1024]` or some big size, but then if you have more than 1024 factors the code will crash. And yes, for 4 it will set two first entries in `List[]` to 2, and set `listSize` to 2. `unsigned listSize=0` must be defined somewhere in global scope as well. And for 6 it will set `List[]={2,3}` and `listSize=2`. That's OK.

Comment: I suggest you print out the array `pvalues` to prove to yourself that it contains a list of primes (especially, that it contains `2`). If it doesn't, check the code used to generate the primes. This is basic step by step debugging. I gave you a general approach, but this is not a free "write and debug my code for me" site - rather, it is a "I seem to be stuck; can anyone unstick me" site? I think that pointing out that your `p` array did not contain primes (which is how you used it) counts as "unsticking". Now you need to do some work...

Comment: @WillNess - thanks for the edit. I had done this on my phone and you can't preview the formatting...

Comment: @rakib_cse06 your code with my edit becomes prime factorization by trial division using all numbers, not just primes; if you factorize just one number it is not worth it to pre-generate primes just to factorize one number. But for more than just a few, then yes, you need to pre-calculate them, and sieve *of Eratosthenes* is your best option.

Comment: @WillNess - if you have more than 1024 factors your number is greater than 2^1024 - and that doesn't fit in an integer (not even a long long integer...)

Comment: but now that I've looked into the Q, it appears that SIZE is 1000000. So no worries. :)

Comment: @willness - I agree it (1000000) is more than adequate. It is the least of the worries in this code.

Comment: @WillNess dude I tried with only size 10 but it didn't work

Comment: @Floris dude I checked the values of pvalues and it contains all prime .

Comment: @rakib_cse06 that is a good start. Next print values in the inner loop of primeFactorize to see how factorization is or isn't happening. You are using the list of primes, right?

Comment: I have edited my answer, giving complete code that works as expected. The I/O could be cleaner... Let me know if this doesn't work for you - and how.

Comment: Cleaned up the I/O as well now.

Comment: Glad it works. `scansf_s` is specific to your platform... what I wrote is more "general C code". The difference is irrelevant for the algorithm. Are you able to "accept" the answer to a closed question?

Answer (score 1):

```
void prime(void){
    long i,j;
    p[0]=1;
    p[1]=1;
    for(i=2;i<=(long)sqrt((double)SIZE);i++)
        if(p[i]==0)
            for(j=2;j*i<SIZE;j++)//<=SIZE ---> <SIZE
                p[i*j]=1;
}

void primeFactorize( long n ){
    listSize = 0;
    long sqrtN = (long)sqrt((double)n);//
    for( long i = 2; i <= sqrtN; i++ ) { //i = 0 ---> i = 2 and p[i] ---> i (Same below)
        while( n % i == 0 ) {//possible [if statement] is omitted
            n /= i;//!
            List[listSize] = i;//!
            listSize++;
        }
    }
    if( n > 1 )
    {
        List[listSize] = n;
        listSize++;
    }
}
```

Comment: but dude @BLUEPIXY if i use i why should i generate p[i] . it didn't work if use p[i] . instead of i .

Comment: @rakib_cse06  at function `prime()`, set `p[i]` to `1` or `0`. i think it cannot be used in function `primeFactorize` that's obvious.

Comment: it didn't work if i use p[i] and crash again

Comment: i don't know. it work fine to me.

Comment: void prime(void)
{
  long i,j;
  pflags[0]=1;
  pflags[1]=1;
  for(i=2;i<=sqrt(SIZE);i++)  // prime generate part
    if(pflags[i]==0)
      for(j=2;j*i<SIZE;j++)
        pflags[i*j]=1;
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    if(pflags[i]==0) pvalues[j++]=i;
  }     
}

Comment: dude @BLUEPIXY void primeFactorize( long n ){
    listSize = 0;
    long sqrtN = (long)sqrt((double)n);//
 for( long i = 2; pvalues[i] <= sqrtN; i++ ) 
 { //i = 0 ---> i = 2 and p[i] ---> i (Same below)
        while( n % pvalues[i] == 0 )
     {//possible [if statement] is omitted
         n /= pvalues[i];//!
         List[listSize] = pvalues[i];//!
                  listSize++;
              }
    }
    if( n > 1 )
    {
        List[listSize] = n;
        listSize++;
    }
}
it show me the output is 4 for 4 , 6 for 6 .

Comment: @rakib_cse06  i suspect a problem with  `pvalues`.

Comment: do u run this @BLUEPIXY ?

Comment: this is your task. variable pvalues[i] is redundant if proposed, so you want use p[i], set p[i] to 0 or prime (itself).

Comment: @rakib_cse06 I see BLUEPIXY already proposed using just `i` instead of `p[i]` or `pvalues[i]`.

Comment: @WillNess dude if I use i why i should generate prime separately ?